# pyspark-invalid syntax error in map tranformation function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i am new to python and spark  and started learning pyspark . can some one help me to execute below program its giving me error :

```py
airportsNameAndCityNames = airportsInUSA.map(lambda x : x.split(COMMA_DELIMITER) {return "{}, {}".format(x.split(COMMA_DELIMITER)[1],x.split(COMMA_DELIMITER)[2])})
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Below code which I am trying to execute in terminal using spark-submit cmd

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("airports").setMaster("local[*]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
    airports = sc.textFile("file:///home/vikram/Desktop/pyspark_tutorial_udemey/in/airports.text")
    COMMA_DELIMITER = ",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"
    airportsInUSA = airports.filter(lambda line : line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER)[3] == "\"United   States\"")

    airportsNameAndCityNames = airportsInUSA.map(lambda x : x.split(COMMA_DELIMITER) {return "{}, {}".format(x.split(COMMA_DELIMITER)[1],x.split(COMMA_DELIMITER)[2])})
    airportsNameAndCityNames.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/vikram/Desktop/pyspark_tutorial_udemey/in/airports_in_usa.text")
```

Comment: Please format your code to Python format.

Answer (score 0):

Below line, doesn't seems to be correct python syntax:

```
airportsNameAndCityNames = airportsInUSA.map(lambda x : x.split(COMMA_DELIMITER) {return "{}, {}".format(x.split(COMMA_DELIMITER)[1],x.split(COMMA_DELIMITER)[2])})
```

But I think you are trying to extract Airport Name and City, hence this can be simplified as below:

```
>>> airportsNameAndCityNames = airportsInUSA.map(lambda x : "{}, {}".format(x.split(COMMA_DELIMITER)[1], x.split(COMMA_DELIMITER)[2]))
>>> airportsNameAndCityNames.take(3)
['OHARE, CHICAGO', 'MIDWAY, CHICAGO', 'JFK, New York']
>>>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks,
Hussain Bohra